# systemd service not executing script?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, systemd, systemctl

I'm using a Debian 9.11 system. I ran into a problem where systemd service runs my script but does not produce the desired result.

I created a script named `my_autossh.sh` and put it under `/usr/bin`. The content of the script is as follows.

```
autossh -f -n -T -N -o "ServerAliveInterval=60" -D 7070 username@www.abc.com
```

And then I created a file named `my_autossh.service` and put it under `/etc/systemd/system`. The content of the file is as follows.

```
[Unit]
Description=autossh connection with www.abc.com for VPN service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/my_autossh.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then I give execution permissions to both files by executing the following

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/my_autossh.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/systemd/system/my_autossh.service
```

And then tried to start the service by executing

```
sudo systemctl enable my_autossh.service
sudo systemctl start my_autossh.service
```

Running `sudo systemctl status my_autossh.service` returns the following result

> ● my_autossh.service - autossh connection with www.abc.com for VPN service 
>   service    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_autossh.service;
>   enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
>    Active: inactive (dead) since Thu
>   2020-01-16 11:24:09 CST; 6min ago 
>   Process: 8196 ExecStart=/bin/bash
>   /usr/bin/my_autossh.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>   Main PID:
>   8196 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Jan 16 11:24:09 tlt-p003 systemd[1]: Started autossh connection with
>   www.abc.com for VPN service.
>  Jan 16 11:24:09 tlt-p003
>   autossh[8214]: starting ssh (count 1)

However when I run `ps aux | grep` to check if autossh is running, it isn't. Running `/usr/bin/my_autossh.sh` does start autossh. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run a systemd with `Type=simple`, then you want to run that service in foreground, which means it should block while the service is alive, rather than forking a background daemon and exiting.

The autossh `-f` option puts it in background, so it's doing the opposite of what you want. Drop that option and this should work.

Additionally, you'll want to launch autossh from the shell script using the `exec` command, which will replace the shell with autossh in the same process. This makes it so that autossh is a direct child process of systemd, so whenever systemd tries to interact with it (for example, send it a signal when trying to stop it), it will be sending the signal directly to the autossh process and not to a shell that's running it.

Putting it all together, you should modify your shell script to read:

```
exec autossh -n -T -N -o "ServerAliveInterval=60" -D 7070 username@www.abc.com
```

Note that you don't really need a separate shell script for this command-line, it doesn't use any features of the shell that are not supported or work differently in systemd... So you could simply use that directly in the `ExecStart=` of your unit file:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -n -T -N -o "ServerAliveInterval=60" -D 7070 username@www.abc.com
```

Comment: Switching to `Type=forking` might be a better choice, as it lets systemd distinguish between the daemon "still starting" and "fully started" (depending on whether it's been written properly).

Comment: It's the opposite of best practice to use `forking`.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504374/5132